# Updating Static DB in Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade

I have an app I need to update with new data for the DB. There's nothing else there to update, no schema changes, no code changes. All I want to do is add some rows to a DB that the user can't modify.

Normally on first install, I copy the DB from `assets/`. After that, when the program runs, I check whether the DB file exists in `/data/data/my.package/databases` and if it does, I don't copy a second time.

Now, the new version of the app will have the full DB intact, and I want to add the new rows for those who have the old version. I have a few options:

- Use the `onUpgrade()` function of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to insert the rows. I don't want to do this because there are many rows, and I'd rather put them in the `assets/` folder to be imported. Is there a way to access `assets/` from within `onUpgrade()`?
- Delete and recreate the DB on every launch. This is wasteful, but it ensures that the full DB is there no matter what previous version of the app was installed.
- Do a check to see the previous version of the app that was installed and selectively delete the DB at first launch to have the DB with new rows copied from `assets/` only on the first launch. For this, I can't quite figure out what I should check. There is no way to know the old app version when running. I thought of using `PackageInfo.firstInstallTime` or `PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime` and checking for a time where, if the user installed/updated before that, then they obviously have the first version I'm looking for. I know that's error-prone, but I've taken the app off the market right now, so I have some leeway here.

An alternative way of phrasing this questions is: If I'm upgrading an app and I have some files in `/data/data/my.package/*` that I either want to delete or update, based on the version change, how can I accomplish that since I can't know what previous version was installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onUpgrade` callback tells you both the old and new versions.

Comment: But is there a way to access `assets/` from there? I can't pass a `Context`.

Comment: You can save the context in your `SQLiteOpenHelper`-derived constructor.